# How do hibernate relationship annotations (@OneToOne, @OneToMany etc) work

Tags: hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

Lets say there is an entity Student which has a one to many relationship with an entity Subject which is lazily loaded. @OneToMany annotation is used to specify the relationship. I would like to understand the internal workings of hibernate on how this annotation is handled.

Comment: [It's called open source for a reason you know](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) :)

Comment: Its open source, but i need to know which class to look. Does it have any annotation processor that handles this? Lets say the student object is populated but the subjects is not due to lazy loading; when i call student.getSubjects() what actually happens. Thats what i want to know

Comment: The annotation is just a marker, the real magic is done with "weaving" aka bytecode manipulation - upon load the classes are effectively rewritten to create things like relations and lazy loading.

Comment: @fvu : I would like to know some detail of that process. Thats why i asked the question. Is there any link that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an instance of Student from the data read in the database, Hibernate initializes the `subjects` collection with an instance of its own implementation of Collection (which well' call PersistentCollection).

This PersistentCollection is not initialized initially, and doesn't contain any data. The first time any method of this collection is called, a SQL query is executed to load all the subjects of the student, and the subjects are then cached inside the collection for all subsequent method calls.

Comment: I have another question. Can you let me know how hibernate knows at runtime that the collection needs to be lazily loaded? Does it manipulate bytecode at compile time or is the annotation available in runtime?

Comment: Yes, the annotation is available at runtime. When the session factory is created, Hibernate analizes all the entity classes.